# how to run beforeEach before `before` hook

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mocha.js

I have the following code.

```js
describe("mytest", () => {

   beforeEach(() => {
      console.log("first");
   })

   context("first context", () => {
      before(() => {
         console.log("second");
      })

   })
 
})
```

What I want to achieve is that I want `first` to get printed first and then `second`. It seems like the problem is `before` hook. `beforeEach` runs before each test case, but not before `before` hook.  Any ideas ?

Comment: Isn't `before` supposed to run before all of the `beforeEach`? Have you tried calling `beforeAll`?

Comment: There's no `beforeAll` at all. I think I am using mocha

Comment: *I think I am using mocha* - I'm not sure what's the meaning of this. Is Mocha in use or not? If it is, why does the question mention Jest? Any way, this is XY problem. This is not how before/beforeAll works. If you have a specific problem to solve, ask about it and not about unworkable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify your DSL in your question. I am assuming you are using [BDD](https://mochajs.org/#bdd). I am not sure how Jest is used here, if this is a Mocha unit test?

In order to run your suite, you will need tests that actually get evaluated.

In the case of the inner-context, you are calling `before` prior to calling `beforeEach`. To reverse your call, you could change `before` to `beforeEach` inside the `context`.

```js
let step = 0;

mocha.setup('bdd');
chai.should();

describe("mytest", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    console.log(`[before each ${step}] first`);
    step++;
  });

  it('outer', () => {
    [].length.should.equal(0);
  });

  context("first context", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      console.log(`[before ${step}] second`);
    });

    it('inner', () => {
      [].length.should.equal(0);
    });
  });
});


mocha.run();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mocha/2.2.5/mocha.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chai/3.2.0/chai.js"></script>
<div id="mocha"></div>
```